# np.exp(x) when x is small

Tags: python, numpy, exp

I tried the following:

```
import  numpy as np

x = -1.20831312e+05
print np.exp(x)     # answer: x = 0.0
print np.expm1(x)   # answer: x = -1.0
```

According to Wolfram, it should be `4.24578... × 10^-52477`. How can I get around of this? I need to compare `np.exp(x)` for small value of `x`.

Comment: 10^-52477 ...???

Comment: is `4.24578... × 10^-52477` not `0` *enough*?

Comment: this is why I said I need to compare `np.exp` for different values of `x`.

Comment: @aloha `exp` is a strictly monotonous function, you can compares the `x`s directly.

Answer (score 5):

You are going to have to work with a logarithmic scale. As suggested by @norrius, you could simply work with the x's, but if you want to turn it into scientific notation, try the following:

```
def exp_to_sci(x):
  coeff, exp = np.modf(x / np.log(10.0))
  return 10**(coeff + 1), exp - 1
```

If you try it on your example you'll get:

```
>>> exp_to_sci(-1.20831312e+05)
(4.2457778774122303, -52477.0)
```

which are the same coefficient and exponent that you got from Wolfram.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sympy` or `bigfloat`:

```
>>> x = -1.20831312e+05
>>> 
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> sp.exp(x)
4.24577787737720e-52477
>>> 
>>> import bigfloat
>>> bigfloat.exp(x)
BigFloat.exact('4.2457778773771979e-52477', precision=53)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the value in numpy as a 64 bit floating point number.  The smallest non-zero number you can store in this way is `2^(1-1023) = 2^-1022`.

Since your number is waaaay smaller than that, it is stored as `0.0`.

Comment: And the smallest positive *quadruple* precision number (128-bit), if your system has those, is around `10^−4965`... For all intents and purposes, `10^-52477` is zero.